# Bottom div within td, zero margin

Tags: css, html, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyTitle</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-image:url('images/my.png');
            /*width:100%;*/
            height:100%;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:100%;
            /*background-position:0,0,0,0px;
            background-position:center;*/
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
        style="height:100%; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: Red; border-color:Yellow;">
        <tr style="background-color: Green;">
            <td style="background-color: Blue; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom:0px;">
                <div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color:Silver;">
                    <button type="submit">Some text</button>
                    <p style="">Another text</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

FF4. The window is blue, it means td fills the whole window. The div has zero margins, td has zero paddings. Nevertheless, there is a blue rectangle between the div and the bottom edge of the window. How to avoid it? Margin-bottom: -16px; is not an option.

Thank you.

Comment: How about posting a URL so we can see the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome: http://sybicit.com/index2.htm Thank you for being interested in my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `p` element - specifically its `margin-bottom`.

Collapsing margins are the reason this is happening:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

You can fix it in this instance with `overflow: hidden` on the `div` which is the parent of the `p`.

Your code: http://jsbin.com/enote5

Your code with the fix: http://jsbin.com/enote5/2

(or you could just remove the `margin` on the `p`, if you like)